# How to compare 2 arrays and split in 3 groups?

Tags: arrays, perl

Let's say I have these arrays

```
my @new = qw/a b c d e/;
my @old = qw/a b   d e f/;
```

and I would like to them compared, so I get 3 new arrays containing the differences

- an array with the elements that are in `@new` and not in `@old` : c
- an array with the elements that are not in `@new` and in `@old` : f
- an array with the elements that are in both `@new` and `@old` : a b d e

I am thinking about the `exists` function, but that only works for hashes I suppose.

**Update**: I messed up the letter examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that I've used many, many times.

```
sub compute_sets {
    my ($ra, $rb) = @_;
    my (@a, @b, @ab, %a, %b, %seen);

    @a{@$ra} = ();
    @b{@$rb} = ();

    foreach (keys %a, keys %b) {
        next if $seen{$_}++;

        if (exists $a{$_} && exists $b{$_}) {
            push(@ab, $_);
        }
        elsif (exists $a{$_}) {
            push(@a, $_);
        }
        else {
            push(@b, $_);
        }
    }

    return(\@a, \@b, \@ab);
}
```

It returns references to arrays containing the elements in the first/second/both lists:

```
my @new = qw/a b c d e/;
my @old = qw/a b   d e f/;

my ($new_only, $old_only, $both) = compute_sets(\@new, \@old);

say 'new only: ', join ' ', @$new_only; # c
say 'old only: ', join ' ', @$old_only; # f
say 'both: ', join ' ', @$both;         # e a b d
```

Answer (score 4):

See [How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?--How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?) in the Perl FAQ.

Comment: That doesn't give the desired grouping. With that I get. intersection: a b d e. difference: c f. union: a b c d e f.

Comment: The main idea of that answer is "Use a hash"

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE2: As Michael Carman points out, my algorithm will fail if elements repeat. So a fixed solution uses one more hash:

```
my (%count, %old);
$count{$_} = 1 for @new;
$old{$_}++ or $count{$_}-- for @old;
# %count is now really like diff(1)    

my (@minus, @plus, @intersection);
foreach (keys %count) {
    push @minus, $_        if $count{$_}  < 0;
    push @plus, $_         if $count{$_}  > 0;
    push @intersection, $_ if $count{$_} == 0;
};
```

UPDATE: Looks like this solution also covers what's in the FAQ:

```
    push @difference, $_ if $count{$_};
    push @union, $_;
```

Comment: agreed, but the FAQ has `@union`. I upped your solution--which I think it a good one, but commented that the FAQ does not *cover* this in the same way.

Comment: This can fail if an array contains repeated elements. e.g. if "a" appears once in `@new` and twice in `@old` it's count would be -1 and it would be flagged as only existing in `@old` instead of both.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing out. Also +1 for submitting a sub and not bare code.

Answer (score 2):

See also [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aDiff)

Answer (score 2):

List::Compare handles this type of problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

my @new = qw/a b c d e/;
my @old = qw/a b   d e f/;

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@new, \@old);

# an array with the elements that are in @new and not in @old : c
my @Lonly = $lc->get_Lonly;
print "\@Lonly: @Lonly\n";

# an array with the elements that are not in @new and in @old : f
my @Ronly = $lc->get_Ronly;
print "\@Ronly: @Ronly\n";

# an array with the elements that are in both @new and @old : a b d e
my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;
print "\@intersection: @intersection\n";

__END__
** prints

@Lonly: c
@Ronly: f
@intersection: a b d e
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @new = qw/a b c d e/;
my @old = qw/a b   d e f/;
my %new = map{$_ => 1} @new;
my %old = map{$_ => 1} @old;

my (@new_not_old, @old_not_new, @new_and_old);
foreach my $key(@new) {
    if (exists $old{$key}) {
        push @new_and_old, $key;
    } else {
        push @new_not_old, $key;
    }
}
foreach my $key(@old) {
    if (!exists $new{$key}) {
        push @old_not_new, $key;
    }
}

print Dumper\@new_and_old;
print Dumper\@new_not_old;
print Dumper\@old_not_new;
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'd',
          'e'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'c'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'f'
        ];
```