# comparing two files

Tags: perl, comparison, diff

I have two file

file1 contents are as below

===================================================

```
OUTPUT1:---------
    orange
    india
    US

xx

OUTPUT2:---------

    orange-1
    india-1
    US-1
xx
```

===================================================

file2 contents are as below

```
OUTPUT1:---------
    orange
    india
    US

xx

OUTPUT2:---------
    orange-1
    india-1
    US-2
xx
```

===================================================

I want difference of two as below

```
-----------------------
OUTPUT1: No evolution
----------------------
OUTPUT2: Evolution found
Before:US-1
After:US-2
----------------------
```

Is it possible to write script in perl with above requirement

any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

No perl, but something more awesome: `diff`!

It compares files:

```
[blender@arch Desktop]$ diff file1.txt file2.txt 
11c11
<     US-1
---
>     US-2
```

`11c11` says that the changed text starts on line 11, character 11.

Comment: So now diff gives us "uncontextual" changes, which record has that US-1 => US-2 change? I claim that simple diff by itself is not enough.

Comment: How is it uncontextual? It gives you the row and column of the changed text. But this is quite impractical to do, as using XML or a database would make all this text-comparing stuff unnecessary.

Comment: The rows exist in the context of records "Output-1" etc. You've lost the semantics of the data because diff is working in lines of text rather than records. Look at the original requirement, it shows the contextual output required.

Comment: Then split the text files by the `xx` strings and compare both chunks. I still think this is overkill in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

[Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~tyemq/Algorithm-Diff-1.1902/lib/Algorithm/Diff.pm#diff) should do the job. It works on arrays (i.e. you can parse whatever input format you like) and generates diff-like output.

However, it might turn out the LCS algorithm is a bit of overkill for the task, and you should just go with [hash tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421463/how-to-compare-2-arrays-and-split-in-3-groups/5421788) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Possible in Perl, for sure, it's a pretty powerful language.

The degree of difficulty will be affected by the assumptions we can make about the data. Is it sorted? How big are the files.

If the data is unsorted and the files are too large to be held entirely in memory then you may need to adopt a pipeline approach, first sorting and then "diffing", and in which case if you have  access to Unix heritage tools such as diff and sort you may not even need Perl.

Assuming you want to use Perl, I'd suggest looking at the problem in stages:

1. Identify "records", which span multiple lines. Write code to consume a single file and build a representation of each record.
2. Solve the sort problem, if need be build an intermediate file containing the sorted records.
3. Do the diff across the two sorted files, if you can build a hash of one entire file in memory this is easy, otherwise you need to fetch records from one file or the other depending upon which one has the "next" record.
4. Having indentified a change print out the details in the desired format

Comment: Hello djna,

look like suitable input for me but I am new to perl and it is possible that someone can help me to write script on this.. I don't know if this is valid request or not